# What are the odds of a triangle, if vertices are picked at random from an $m\times n$ square grid?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, triangles

In an $m\times n $ square grid (assume $m,n >2$), three distinct points are picked randomly.  What are the odds they make a non-degenerate triangle?  In the limit the odds go to one.

This is related to [Sylvester's 4-point problem](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SylvestersFourPointProblem/), but I'm interested in the same problem on a discrete grid.  The limit is 25/36 ~ 0.694444.  On a 21x21 grid the odds of a quadrilateral are 1053055398/1554599970 ~ 0.67738.  The odds of a triangle for a grid might solve this question.

EDIT:  The square case is [A000938](https://oeis.org/A000938). A [table of values](http://iq0.com/collinear-triples.txt) has been made.

Comment: In what limit do the odds go to zero?  For large $m,n$ I would be sure the probability goes to $1$.  The only way you fail is if the points are colinear.  The link you give is for four points making a convex quadrilateral, not three points making a triangle.

Comment: Right, one.  I was going to ask about odds of three in a row.  Odds of that go to zero.  I made that fix.

Comment: Did you use some kind of formula to calculate the number of collinear triples or did you count them (brute force)?

Comment: The tables are brute force

Comment: I found a recursive formula, maybe it can be improved, I'll check one of these days.

Answer (score 2):

Let the stepsize be $(p,q)$, where $p$ and $q$ are coprime.  Suppose ${p\over q}\gt {m\over n}$, so the steps reach from one $n$-side to the other.   The number of consecutive 3 in a row is $(m-2p)(n-2q)$, the number of 3 points chosen from 4 in a row is another $2(m-3p)(n-3q)$, then 3 out of 5 another $3(m-4p)(n-4q)$ until one of the factors goes negative.  If $m =kp+a$ where $0\le a\lt p$, and $n \ge kq$, the sum is
$$\sum_{i=2}^k (i-1)(m-ip)(n-iq)\\ =mn{k\choose2}-2(mq+np){k+1\choose3}  +pq(k^3-k)(3k+2)/12$$
On average, $k\approx \frac mp-\frac12$.  To two leading orders, this is $$m^3n/2p^2-m^2n/p\\
-(m^4q+m^3np)/3p^3+(mq+np)m^2/2p^2\\
+m^4q/4p^3-m^3q/3p^2$$
$=m^3/12p^3(2pn-mq)-m^2n/2p+m^3q/6p^2$.  It is to be divided by $mn\choose3$ to give a probability of  $${1\over p^2n^2}-{mq\over2p^3n^3}-{3\over mn^2p}+ 
{q\over n^3p^2}$$

On average, a fraction $6/\pi^2$ of the $q$-numbers from 1 to $pn/m$ are coprime to $p$.  Summed over q, I get
$${9\over 2\pi^2 pnm}-{15\over\pi^2m^2n}$$
This is doubled to take into account steps in the direction $(p,-q)$, then summed over $p$ from 1 to $m/2$.
$${9\log m\over \pi^2mn}-{15\over2\pi^2mn}$$
Lastly sum over those $p,q$ on the other side of the diagonal,, to get
$$9\log mn-15\over \pi^2mn$$

Comment: For a 21x21 square, the actual odds are 130264/14197260 ~ 0.00917529.  Your formula gives 0.0125908

Comment: If I replace $\log m$ and $\log n$ by $\log (m/2)$ and $\log( n/2)$, it is 0.00972, but that is a tweak

Comment: See how well the tweak compares to the table of values I posted for a few random m n values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have found out so far:

In a grid of $n \times m$ points, let's denote the number of triangles by $t(n,m)$ and the number of sets of $3$ collinear points by $c(n,m)$, then their sum is the number of sets containing $3$ points in that grid, so
$$t(n,m)+c(n,m)=\binom{n\cdot m}{3}$$
I found it easier to focus on the values of $c(n,m)$, and my first attempt was to create a recursive formula using the following strategy:

$3$ collinear points in an $(n+1)\times m$-grid can be contained in the "upper" or the "lower" $n \times m$-grid, or their "outer" points must be contained in the first respectively the last row. For this, if we count $c(n,m)$ twice, we have double-counted the $c(n-1,m)$ collinear $3$-sets completely contained in the intersecting $(n-1) \times m$ grid which we have to subtract. For the number of collinear $3$-sets with points in the first an last row, there are $m$ vertical line segments with $n-1$ inner points each, and there are $\binom{m}{2}$ non-vertical southwest-to-northeast lines (that we have to count twice to also count southeast-to-northwest) that might or might not have inner points in the grid. The number of inner points in such a line segment depends on the vertical and horizontal distances and their $\gcd$, it evaluates to $\gcd(\Delta x,\Delta y)-1$, where the $-1$ excludes the endpoint of the line segment (we only want to count the "inner" points). There are $m-k$ such line segments with horizontal distance $k$ (where $1 \le k \le m-1$), all with vertical distance $n$, so the resulting recursive formula is:
$$\begin{align}
c(n+1,m) &= 2c(n,m)-c(n-1,m)+m(n-1)+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)(\gcd(n,k)-1)\\
&= 2c(n,m)-c(n-1,m)+m(n-1)-m(m-1)+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)\gcd(n,k)\\
&= 2c(n,m)-c(n-1,m)+m(n-m)+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)\gcd(n,k)
\end{align}$$
For a positive integer $m$, knowing that $c(0,m)=0$ and $c(1,m)=\binom{m}{3}$, we can calculate the values of $c(n,m)$, which is (if we store the intermediate values in an array) more efficient than counting brute force.

Another attempt resulted in an explicit formula which unfortunately contains a double-sum with $\gcd$'s:

In the grid of size $n \times m$ we find $n\binom{m}{3}$ vertical and $m\binom{n}{3}$ horizontal $3$-sets of collinear points. As above, we have to add twice the number of non-horizontal southwest-to-northeast collinear $3$-sets. We can count these summing them up by their possible $\Delta x$-$\Delta y$ combinations counting the inner points using a $\gcd$-formula like in the first attempt:

$$\begin{align}
c(n,m) &= n\binom{m}{3}+m\binom{n}{3}+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}(m-k)(n-l)(\gcd(k,l)-1)\\
&= n\binom{m}{3}+m\binom{n}{3}-2\binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}(m-k)(n-l)\gcd(k,l)
\end{align}$$
Maybe someone can find a way to eliminate the $\gcd$'s from one of the formulas.